# Build subproject and dependent subprojects

Tags: sbt

Assume I have a multi-project build with the following dependencies:

- Projekt A
- Projekt B depends on A
- Project C
- Project D depends on C

Now I have a change in project C. When I compile/test in sub-project C, I want the commands to be automatically applied to D subsequently (because D relies on C and I may have broken an API), but not to A and B.

Is there a way in sbt to say "compile this sub-project and all projects that depend on it"?

This would be equivalent to [`buildDependents` in Gradle](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_plugin.html#sec:java_tasks), or [`--alsoMakeDependents` in Maven](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-multiple-modules.html), I believe.

If it doesn't exist yet, helpful hints on how to implement such a task are also most welcome.

Comment: I think by default `sbt compile` will only build those projects affected by the change.

Comment: No, @lutzh, there's no equivalent to `--also-make-dependents`. You could open a feature request for it.

Comment: Thanks @DaleWijnand , will do.

Comment: https://github.com/sbt/sbt/issues/2976